# Calculate the signed area of piecewise constant functions without using integration

Tags: python, numpy

I have defined a step function in Python using the following code. The function takes in an array `a` and `x` values, applies some calculations, and returns a step function `f`. Additionally, I have defined two helper functions `rect` and `psi_j_n`. I'd like to calculate the signed area of the product of `step_function` and `psi_j_n(x, -10, 0)` without using the integral because it is a rectangle, and that's the area I'm looking for.

My initial attempt:

```
signed_area = 0
for x_values in x:
    signed_area += step_function(x_values, a) * psi_j_n(x_values, -10, 0)

signed_area
```

is incorrect because I am missing the length of the base of the rectangle. When I calculate the area by hand, I should get 0.012.

**Update**
I used the following code to define the step function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Define the step function
def step_function(x, a):
    def rect(x):
        return np.where((x >= 0) & (x < 1), 1, 0)
    
    f = np.sum([a[k-1] * rect(x - k) for k in range(1, len(a) + 1)], axis=0)
    return f

# Set the random seed for reproducibility
np.random.seed(42)

# Generate random values for a_k
N = 10
a = np.array([-0.25091976,  0.90142861,  0.46398788,  0.19731697, -0.68796272,
       -0.68801096, -0.88383278,  0.73235229,  0.20223002,  0.41614516])
#a = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, size=N)

# Define the x-values for plotting
x = np.arange(0, N + 1, 0.01)

# Evaluate the step function at x
y = step_function(x, a)

# Plot the step function
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.title('Step Function Plot')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

It produces the picture

[image]

The following code defines instead the function  `psi_j_n(x, j, n)`:

```
def psi(x):
    if 0 <= x < 0.5:
        return 1
    elif 0.5 <= x < 1:
        return -1
    else:
        return 0

def psi_j_n(x, j, n):
    return 2**(j/2) * psi(2**j * x - n)
```

Then, I would like to calculate the product of `step_function(x, a)` and `psi_j_n(x, j, n)`.

Comment: Please, post a [mre]. Your code must be as small as possible, and yet be runable as is. What you posted isn't: we don't have definition of `step_function`, `x`, `psi_j_n`, ...

Comment: Besides, what do you mean by "without integral"? As far as I can see, what you're doing IS computing an integral.

Comment: Excuse me, I posted now a reproducible example.

Comment: How do you get the value 0.012?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, the only missing thing in your code is the base of the rectangle. You choose it to 0.01, so why not just multiply the result by 0.01?

```py
signed_area = 0
for x_values in x:
    signed_area += 0.01*step_function(x_values, a) * psi_j_n(x_values, -10, 0)

signed_area
```

Note that I could have multiplied by 0.01 the final result instead, that would be more efficient (but anyway that code is not efficient at all; see next how to make it so). But putting it there make it easier to adapt the code to cases where the area of each rectangle is not constant.

## More efficient version

What you need is a vectorized version of `psi`. As is, you can call it only with scalar values, and it return a scalar value.

```py
psi(0.1)
# 1
psi(0.6)
# -1
psi(2)
# 0
```

We would like to also be able to call

```py
psi([0.1, 0.2, 2])
# array([1,-1,0])
```

That can be done many way. The trick is to avoid calling for loop at all cost. One way could be

```py
def psi(x):
    return ((x>=0)&(x<1))*(2*(x<0.5)-1)
```

Or you could use `np.where` as you already did for another function.

Now that psi is "vectorized", and so is therefore `psi_j_n`, you can just compute the multiplication of `psi_j_n(x,-10,0)` (which now makes sense, even if `x` is an array) and `step_function(x,a)` aka `y` in your code.

So simply

```py
psi_j_n(x,-10,0)*y
```

And then compute the integral of that (you said you didn't want any integrals, but since your attempt is computing that integral, I take you meant that you didn't want to have to calculate the formulation of this integral on a piece of paper before coding).

The simpler way to do that with rectangle method is

```py
(psy_j_n(x,-10,0)*y).sum()*0.01)
```

Which is indeed `0.012585459687500009`